# Setting the minimum value of yAxes in afreechart android

Tags: java, android, jfreechart

I am using afreechart to plot a timeseries as in this [example code](http://code.google.com/p/afreechart/source/browse/trunk/afreechart_sample/src/org/afree/chart/demo/view/TimeSeriesChartDemo01View.java)
However if the chart is panned vertically you reach the areas of the negative y axes. I want to avoid that and would want to set the min and max for both y and x axes.
I tried doing something like the below:-

```
ValueAxis yaxes=plot.getRangeAaxis();
yaxes.setRange(0,100);
```

But this does not seem to work and I am still able to pan the chart into non-negative y values area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it myself.. I was extending from the class DemoView as in the example. I just changed some values as below:-

```
 this.domainMovable=true;
 this.rangeMovable=false;
```

It might be a dirty way but does my job